# My custom tooltip isn't moving along with the corresponding element that I hover over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My custom tooltip isn't moving along with the corresponding element that I hover over.  Instead it is fixed to one location on the page.  The content of the tooltip is correct for the corresponding element but its location is just static.  Please can someone advise?

PHP:

```
 $arrayAuthors = explode(',', $authorString);
for($i=0; $i<count($arrayAuthors); $i++){
    $authors .= '<div id="author_'.$i.'" class="authorWrap" onmouseover="pub.showInvite(\'wraptip_'.$i.'\')" onmouseout="pub.unshowInvite(\'wraptip_'.$i.'\')">'.$arrayAuthors[$i].'</div>

                 <div id="wraptip_'.$i.'" class="outerWrap">
                    <div class="innerWarap">
                        <p class="personAuth">Invite '.$arrayAuthors[$i].' to club</p>
                        <p><button class="inviteBtn">Invite</button></p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
    ';
}
```

My CSS:

```
 .authorWrap{
 position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: #F0F0F0;
font-size: 13px;
margin: 10px;
 }

 .outerWrap{
display: none;
width: 100px;
padding: 5px;
color: #fff;    
background: #535663;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 11px;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 6px;
top: 20px;
left: -10px;
 }
```

MY JS:

```
 pub.showInvite =function(idOfDiv){
var divInvite = document.getElementById(idOfDiv);
divInvite.style.display = 'block';
 }

 // UNSHOW INVITE - ONMOUSEOUT
 pub.unshowInvite = function(idOfDiv){
 var divInvite = document.getElementById(idOfDiv);
 divInvite.style.display = 'none';
 }
```

Comment: authorWrap must be positioned relatively, otherwise, your tooltip is positioned absolutely, but in the body context (not as a child of author div)... So add position:relative to .authorWrap.

Comment: @nevermind That works in so far as the toolip appears without disrupting the structure of the rest of the layout.  However, it does not move along with the corresponding hovered-over element.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'not move along'? Do you want to move tooltip once it is shown (to follow mouse position), or something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7wofpev3/

Comment: my tooltip wasn't show directly underneath the corresponding element that I was hovering over.  However, I have the problem solved.  I now just need to move the entire .outerwrap divs inside the .authorwrap divs.  thanks to your help I got this one solved. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple thing ;) You must change `position: absolute;` - that is why your tooltip is always on the same place - use `position: relative;` or something instead.

But if it causes problems with positioning other elements there are several ways to protect your layout from breaking.

I think the simplest will be to place tooltip **inside** coresponding element and than you will be able to stick with `position: absolute;` (but parent element can't be `postion: static;`).

Also, with JavaScript, you can get position from parent element and appear it (possibly with some calculations) to your tooltip - but this is much more complicated way.

Comment: the problem with that is it changes the structure of the layout every time the tooltip appears.